# How to set default parameter with data type object in ADF

Tags: parameters, azure-data-factory

I have a generic pipeline where I want the cluster sizes to be configurable. The idea is to use an **optional** parameter where I can set a default pipeline in the generic pipeline, so I don't have to change many other pipelines that reference this generic pipeline. The parameter definition is shown here below. [image: Parameter overview of generic pipeline]

We now want to use this Object parameter in order to select the cluster size corresponding to our current environment. This is done as follows:

[image: Use parameter in generic pipeline]

This goes well if I pass an explicit value for the Parameter from the outer (calling) pipeline, like so: [image: Call generic pipeline with explicit value configured].

I also want other (unchanged) pipelines that call the generic pipeline to continue running with a default value. Those are called as follows:

[image: Call generic pipeline without explicit value configured]

but that results in the following error:

[image]

Please note: it is not possible to use Dynamic Content to set the default value for a Pipeline Parameter of type Object. Which adaptations should I make in order to correctly set the default value for clusterSizes **as a json object**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the above scenario with the below JSON as object type parameter in a child pipeline.

```
{"name":["Rakesh"],"Age":[22],"nickname":["Laddu"],"luck":[]}
```

I have used `@pipeline().parameters.param1[variables('one')]` expression in the child pipeline and called it from Parent pipeline.

[image]

And I got the same error.

[image]

This is because, when we are not passing any values for the child pipeline parameters from parent pipelines and expecting to take default parameter values for it, **it is taking the type of that value as a String**.

Input for the Execute pipeline activity.

[image]

You can see it took the value as string even though we defined it as an object type.

When I tried with other data types, it took correct types for `int` and `bool` types.

[image]

[image]

But, for the `Object`, `array` and `float` types it took type as string only. This might be a bug in ADF.

As you want the other pipelines to continue with default values, changing the generic pipeline might be the **workaround** in this case.

> Which adaptations should I make in order to correctly set the default value for clusterSizes **as a json object**?

In your generic pipeline, when using that parameter convert that to object with the below expression.

```
@json(string(pipeline().parameters.param1))[variables('one')]
```

With this expression, **the pipelines which requires default values will be converted to JSON object** and **the pipelines which uses the dynamic content parameter values will be converted to string and again converted to JSON object**.